# ItemsSource on Nokia's Here Map control for WP8

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, here-api

Does anyone know how to databind pushpins in the Nokia Map control? Thanks!

Comment: Based on what I've read, I don't think so without using a custom attribute. Based on the reference, they don't seem to want you to create a MapLayer in XAML. You could theoretically, as I implied, create an attached property which accepts a binding to a collection and processes the pins based on changes to the collection. It could also then process the changes asynchronously/incrementally so as not to bog down the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](https://nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit) to add children to the map. The Toolkit contains some [controls](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Maps/MapChildControl.cs) and [extensions](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP8/Maps/MapExtensions.cs) that make this easier to work with.

```
<maps:Map x:Name="myMap">
    <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
        <toolkit:UserLocationMarker x:Name="UserLocationMarker" />
        <toolkit:Pushpin x:Name="MyPushpin" Content="My Position"></toolkit:Pushpin>
    </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```

You can even use templating to bind to a collection of items.

```
<maps:Map x:Name="myMap">
    <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
        <toolkit:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MapItems}">
            <toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding Coordinate}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:MapItemsControl>
    </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```